# flutter IAP how to "Restore Purchases"

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, restore

I am using [flutter_inapp_purchase](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase#-readme-tab-) for my flutter app's IAP of non-Consumable product. For IOS, it does need to include a "Restore Purchases" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased in-app purchases. May I know how to create "Restore" button and initiate the restore process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user?

```
  Future<Null> _buyProduct(IAPItem item) async {
    try {
      PurchasedItem purchased= await 
  FlutterInappPurchase.buyProduct(item.productId);
      print('purcuased - ${purchased.toString()}');
    } catch (error) {
      print('$error');
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _getProduct() async {
    List<IAPItem> items = await FlutterInappPurchase.getProducts(_productLists);
    for (var item in items) {
      print('${item.toString()}');
      this._items.add(item);
    }

    setState(() {
      this._items = items;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Plugin [documentation](https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_inapp_purchase) you can use the API

```
getAvailablePurchases
```

[image]

That looking at the library native code, this method is link to

```
// getAvailablePurchases
- (void)getAvailableItems:(FlutterResult)result {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    flutterResult = result;
}
```

And from Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions):

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> func restoreCompletedTransactions()
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Use this method to restore finished transactions—that is, transactions
>   for which you have already called finishTransaction(_:). You call this
>   method in one of the following situations: To install purchases on
>   additional devices To restore purchases for an application that the
>   user deleted and reinstalled

So adding a Widget Button (the one you like most) is up to you, and you can put it wherever you want.

Then in the onClick event call `getAvailableItems` and manage the previously bought purchases of the users and reinstall them in the user's device.

Comment: Hey, what does your last sentence mean "Manage the previously bought purchases and reinstall them"? Is there something more to do except "getAvailableItems()"?

Comment: @FrederikWitte only the act to persist these purcheses locally on device.

Comment: Isn't that done automatically? I've never seen anyone saving them in local storage or something

Comment: @FrederikWitte actually I didn’t try myself and I’ve never used iap. I only reported what doc says. if you know for ios native experience that a successful call to that methods is enough, so well... that’s it! [-;

Answer (score 10):

For devs using official flutter dev package https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase:

Restore purchases (needed for iOS non-consumable, auto-renewable subscription, or
 non-renewing subscription) is simply calling

`Future<QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse> queryPastPurchases`

which under the hood calls

`_observer.getRestoredTransactions`

What you should do here is to iterate all purchases with status PurchaseStatus.purchased or Purchase.error and call

`InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);`

then validate receipts with Apple and deliver owned purchases

> taken from class InAppPurchaseConnection:
>
> /// You are responsible for completing every [PurchaseDetails] whose
>   /// [PurchaseDetails.status] is [PurchaseStatus.purchased] or   ///
>   [[PurchaseStatus.error]. Completing a [PurchaseStatus.pending]
>   purchase   /// will cause an exception.   ///   /// This throws an
>   [UnsupportedError] on Android.
>
> - If a purchase is not completed ([completePurchase] is not
>     called on the purchase object) from the last app session.
>     Purchase updates will happen when a new app session starts
>     instead.

You will probably do that anyways on the app launch but Apple now requires restore purchases option for all non-consumable and auto-renewable inapp products, otherwise your app will be rejected in the review process.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases

> If your app sells non-consumable, auto-renewable subscription, or
>   non-renewing subscription products, you must provide a UI that allows
>   them to be restored. Your customers expect your content to be
>   available on all their devices and indefinitely; see In-App Purchase
>   for more information.